# How to tell ruby on rails, not to insert to a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a table, with merge replication on it (SQL Server 2005).
There is a **rowguid** column. I want RoR to ignore this column, and not insert into this, and not include this when generating the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this ticket](http://dev.rubyonrails.org/ticket/8913) which proposes a patch to rails.
You can add the following code to a new file `/config/initializers/hidden_columns.rb`:

```
require "activerecord"

class << ActiveRecord::Base 
  def hidden_columns(*hidden) 
    write_inheritable_array("hidden_column", hidden.collect(&:to_s)) 
  end

  def columns_hidden
    read_inheritable_attribute("hidden_column") || [] 
  end 

  def columns 
    unless defined?(@columns) && @columns 
      @columns = connection.columns(table_name, "#{name} Columns").delete_if {|c| columns_hidden.member?(c.name) } 
      @columns.each {|column| column.primary = column.name == primary_key} 
    end 
    @columns 
  end
end
```

Then you can write:

```
hidden_columns :rowguid
```

in the concerned models.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. Somehow RoR doesn't find the hidden_columns method. I'm gettiing a undefined method.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, would be to make a view that hides the column(s). I've done this when bolting a rails app onto a legacy DB in SQL Server.  This way you don't have to mess with / fight rails, and can hide any columns that you want easily...

Comment: easily the best and simplest way to go in my opinion. i wish i had seen this years ago when taking on a legacy project

Answer (score 0):

Answer is same as above

Method needs to be defined as a class method
http://gist.github.com/504745

Comment: Great that you fixed it yourself. "Above" changes though, so I modified my answer.